# Python using dictionary list values to key match a dictionary

Tags: python, list, dictionary, key-value

I'm struggling in python on how to query a dictionary with a value from one list as a key in another. For example:

```
d1 = {"fruit":[5, 3, 3, 3, 4, 2, 4]}

d2 = {0:"apple", 1:"pear", 2:"cherry", 3:"lime", 4:"orange", 5:"mango", 6:"kiwi"}
```

What I'd like to do is create a new dictionary where the fruits are still in a list like in d1 where there are multiples, but with key matched values from d2. Below is the transformation I am looking for.  Kinda like an inner join in sql.

```
d3 = {"fruit":["mango", "lime", "lime", "lime", "orange", "pear", "orange"]}
```

I tried using the code below, but it just nested d2 as a dictionary within rather than matching each value in the list.

```
d3 = {k: d2 for k, v in d1.items()}
>>>{'fruit': {0: 'apple', 1: 'pear', 2: 'cherry', 3: 'lime', 4: 'orange', 5: 'mango', 6: 'kiwi'}}
```

I've been able to combine the two if I convert d1 into a list rather than a dictionary, however it doesn't carry over duplicate entries if there are more than one of each fruit.

```
l1 = [5, 3, 3, 3, 4, 2, 4]
d2 = {0:"apple", 1:"pear", 2:"cherry", 3:"lime", 4:"orange", 5:"mango", 6:"kiwi"}
d3 = {k: d2[k] for k in l1 if k in d2}
>>>{5: 'mango', 3: 'lime', 4: 'orange', 2: 'cherry'}
```

Any guidance would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: `d3 = {'fruit': [d2[i] for i in d1['fruit']]}`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to nest a list comprehension which maps the values from `d2` onto the items in the list:

```
>>> {k:[d2[v] for v in vs] for k, vs in d1.items()}
{'fruit': ['mango', 'lime', 'lime', 'lime', 'orange', 'cherry', 'orange']}
```

Or, expressed another way:

```
>>> {k:list(map(d2.get, vs)) for k, vs in d1.items()}
{'fruit': ['mango', 'lime', 'lime', 'lime', 'orange', 'cherry', 'orange']}
```

(note, the above uses `.get`, so if the value is not in `d2`, it returns `None`